# Finding the closed form of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, recursion

I am looking mostly for keywords, to search and study on examples and techniques on how one goes on finding the closed form expression on a recursive sequence.

I have a problem to solve, which looks like

$${ a_{n+1} = \frac{ma_n + x}{a_n + y} }$$

(I am not writing the exact values, because I am not looking for a solution, just guidance.)

I have seen a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3830533/617101), which is amazing, but I do not understand how one thinks about it.

Comment: A common method in finding closed form expressions for recurrence relations is by using substitution to work with an easier recurrence relation. I'm not certain about how to apply it to a general case though,

Comment: You can also take a look a homogeneous and inhomogeneous generating functions. The standard text is Generatingfunctionology by Wilf though that might be a bit advanced.

Comment: You find the eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}m& x \\ 1 & y\end{pmatrix}$, then you'll have your closed form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a first-order rational difference equation (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_difference_equation)).

$${ a_{n+1} = \frac{ma_n + x}{a_n + y} }=m+\frac{x-m y}{a_n+y}$$
Let $b_n=a_n-m$ to make
$$\frac{m y-x}{b_n+m+y}+b_{n+1}=0$$ Let $c_n=b_n+m+y$ to make
$$\frac{m y-x}{c_n}+c_{n+1}=m+y$$ Let $p=m y-x$ and $q=m+y$ to make
$$\frac{p}{c_n}+c_{n+1}=q$$

If you follow the steps given in the linked page, you should get coething like
$$c_n=\frac{A_n}{B_n}$$ with
$$A_n=K \left(q^2-2 p\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}-q}{p}\right)^n-K q
   \sqrt{q^2-4 p} \left(\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}-q}{p}\right)^n+\left(q^2-2 p\right)
   \left(-\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}+q}{p}\right)^n+q \sqrt{q^2-4 p}
   \left(-\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}+q}{p}\right)^n$$
and
$$B_n=\sqrt{q^2-4 p} \left(\left(-\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}+q}{p}\right)^n-K
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}-q}{p}\right)^n\right)+q \left(K
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4 p}-q}{p}\right)^n+\left(-\frac{\sqrt{q^2-4
   p}+q}{p}\right)^n\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question 100%

Comment: Could you tell what $K$ is here?