# Find $N(\varepsilon)$ for the current sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_1 = a > 0$. And $x_{n + 1} = 6 \frac{1 + x_n}{7 + x_n}$.

We know, that: $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(x_n) = x$ ($x_n$ has limit in $\mathbb{R}$).

We need to find $N(\varepsilon)$, such that:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0  \ \forall n > N(\varepsilon) \  |x_n - x| < \varepsilon$.

The main trouble I have is to compare $x_n$ and $\varepsilon$, because it's hard to get the formula, which depends from $n$.

Comment: You should probably begin by finding $x$.

Comment: Your recurrence gives roots $2,-3$ from which you take first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693), I described to steps to follow for this kind of first-order rational difference equations.

Your problem is a bit simpler and you should arrive at
$$x_n=\frac{-27 (a-2) 4^n-8 (a+3) 9^n}{9 (a-2) 4^n-4 (a+3) 9^n}\tag 1$$ and a said in comments, the limit is either $-3$ or $+2$.

Since $a>0$, using $(1)$ and making $n \to \infty$, the limit is $x=2$.

Simplifying, assuming $a \neq 2$ this case would be more tha easy), we have
$$|x_n-x|=\frac 5 {\frac{a+3 }{a-2}\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n-1}-1 }$$
Now, you look for
$$   \frac{ 5  N(\varepsilon)}{\frac{a+3 }{a-2}\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n-1}-1 }< \varepsilon$$ which does not seem to be too difficult.