# Let $x_0 = 2003$, and let $x_{n+1} = \frac{1 + x_n}{1 - x_n}$ for $n >= $1. Compute $x_{2019}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

> Let $x_0 = 2003$, and let $x_{n+1} = \frac{1 + x_n}{1 - x_n}$ for $n >= $1. Compute $x_{2019}$

I tried expressing $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$.. in terms of previous terms to see if there is a pattern but $n >= 1$ is troubling me. Please help.

Comment: If you have indeed calculated $x_2,x_3,x_4$, what is $x_4$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Note that

$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+2}&=\frac{1+x_{n+1}}{1-x_{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1+\frac{1+x_n}{1-x_n}}{1-\frac{1+x_n}{1-x_n}}\\
&=\frac{1-x_n+1+x_n}{1-x_n-1-x_n}\\
&=-\frac1{x_n}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: From this relation, $x_{2019} = -\frac{1}{x_1}$ but how would we get $x_2$ or $x_1$ seeing as to how we can't substitute $n=0$?

Comment: Professor, then we have $x_{n+2} = x_{n-2}$ so that $x_{2019} = x_{1}$?

Comment: @user 1729 when you substitute, the negative sign and reciprocation disappear I think, so that we get $x_{n} = x_{n-4}$ which is the same as what I wrote.

Comment: @DerekLuna: We have $x_{n+4}=x_n$, so in particular $x_{4n}=2003$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. That gives you $x_{2016}$, from which it’s easy to get $x_{2018}$ and then $x_{2019}$.

Comment: @Brian M Scott, although I wonder if for some people seeing that $x_{2020} = 2003 $ and using the given recurrence might be quicker. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @DerekLuna: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $x_r=\tan(y_r)$

$$x_{n+1}=\tan(y_{n+1})=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+y_n\right)$$

$$\implies\tan(y_{n+r})=\tan(y_n)\text{  if }4\mid r$$

and $$\tan(y_{n+r})=-\dfrac1{\tan(y_n)}\text{  if }r\equiv2\pmod4$$

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693), ou will find how to solve the first-order rational difference equation in the more general case.

For $x_0=a$, this would give after simplifications

$$x_n=\frac{a \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{4}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi 
   n}{4}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{4}\right)-a \sin \left(\frac{\pi    n}{4}\right)}$$