# Is a recursively given series monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, recursion, monotone-functions

The series is given as $a_{n+1}=\frac{8a_{n}-3}{2a_{n}+1}$ and $a_{1}=1$
I have no idea how to prove if this series is monotone or not.
I have tried rearranging the equation to form $a_{n+1}>a_{n}$ but nothing seems to work.

Please if you know how to solve this it would help a ton!

Comment: Have you tried to calculate $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ directly? It should be helpful intuitively

Comment: Well that just gives me $2a_{n}^{2}+7a_{n}+3<0$ which doesn't really prove anything.

Comment: it actually does give you something because if the difference is always positive (or always negative respectively) then you can relate it to the notion of monotonicity. However, your calculation is slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}-3=\frac{2(a_n-3)}{2a_n+1}\tag1$$
$$2a_{n+1} - 1 = \frac{7(2a_n-1)}{2a_n+1} \tag 2$$

Since $a_1=1 > \frac 12>0$, from $(2)$ we know $2a_n-1>0, \forall n$. We also know $a_n < 3, \forall n$ from $(1)$.

Therefore
$$a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{(3-a_n)(2a_n-1)}{2a_n+1}>0.\blacksquare$$

**Remark 1:** We derive $(1)$ and $(2)$ based on the solutions of the characteristic equation $\lambda = \frac{8\lambda - 3}{2\lambda + 1}$ which are $3$ and $\frac 12$.

**Remark 2:** We can derive the closed form solution for $a_n$ easily as follows

Divide $(1)$ by $(2)$ and we obtain

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-3}{2a_{n+1}-1} = \frac 27 \cdot \frac{a_n-3}{2a_n-1} \tag 3$$

Now $(3)$ is a geometric sequence,
$$
\frac{a_n-3}{2a_n-1} = \left( \frac 27 \right)^{n-1} \cdot \frac{8a_1-3}{2a_1+1} 
$$
and the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693), I detailed the steps for the solution of  first-order rational difference equation (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_difference_equation)) $$a_{n+1} = \frac{m\,a_n + x}{a_n + y} $$

With your parameters $m=4$, $x=-\frac 32$ and $y=\frac 12$, the results for $a_n$ are extremely simple.

On the other side, do not forget that, **if** the limit $L$ exists, it is the solution of $L=\frac{8 L-3}{2 L+1}$.

Comment: I think mine and your definition of simple are a little bit off ... But thanks anyway!

Comment: @ViliPerše. This is *relativity* ! Please read the very first line.  Cheers :-)