# nth term of $2,2+\frac{1}{2},2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}},2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}},2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}}}...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

What is the nth term of the sequence: $$2,2+\frac{1}{2},2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}},2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}},2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}}}...$$

in terms of $s_{n-1}$.

I have tried for some time to calculate this but to no avail. Hopefully somebody with a better understanding of the world of sequences could help/point me in the right direction!

Comment: The sequence is $\;x_{n+1}=2+\frac1{x_n}\;$ , with $\;x_0=2\;$ ...Do you need the limit, in case it exists?

Comment: What is $\;S_{n-1}\; $ ...??

Comment: @DonAntonio So I just noticed I left off part of the question where the question is:  Write the nth term of the sequence $s_n$ in terms of $s_{n−1}$. I may be incorrect but this may just be the nth term that you have provided minus one from the term. I am sorry if I haven't phased that well

Comment: Yes, that's the name of the sequence and thus my comment above answers your question.

Comment: Calculate the first few values
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{2}{1} , \frac{5}{2} , \frac{12}{5} , \frac{29}{12} , \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
& then look the sequence up ... https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C12%2C29&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @Mr Nop,  the limit is $\;1+\sqrt2\;$ ...can you see why? It isn't very easy...but also not too hard.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Comment: @DonAntonio. Did you know the formula I wrote in my edit ? For me, it is just beautiful. Cheers.:-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Salut cher ami! No, I really didn't know that beautiful formula. Very nice, indeed !

Comment: @DonAntonio Could you please elaborate in regards to how you got that as the limit, I am interested in the method that you used.

Comment: @DonAntonio is it something to do with the fact that $1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+...}}}}$ is the approximation of $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693), I detailed the steps for solving a first-order rational difference equation such as
$${ a_{n+1} = \frac{ma_n + x}{a_n + y} }=m+\frac{x-m y}{a_n+y}$$
For your case $m=2$, $x=1$ and $y=0$. So, using the initial condition,
$$a_n=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n-\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n } { \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n+\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n}$$

**Edit**

In the documentation of sequence [$A000129$](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C12%2C29&language=english&go=Search) in $OEIS$, there is superb formula given by Peter Luschny in year $2018$. It write
$$a_n=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\, e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{2}}\,\sinh \left(n \cosh ^{-1}(-i)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already know the sequence converges, and that is not trivial as the subsequence $\;\left\{x_{2n}\right\}_{n=0}^\infty\;$ is monotonic *descending* whereas the subsequence $\;\left\{x_{2n+1}\right\}_{n=0}^\infty\;$ is monotonic *ascending* ( yet both sequences are appropiatedly bounded and converge to the same non-zero finite limit ), and if we put $\;\alpha=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n\;$  , we can then use arithmetic of limits and get

$$\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2+\frac1{x_n}\right)=2+\frac1\alpha\implies\alpha^2-2\alpha-1=0$$

and solving the above quadratic we get that the only plausible limit is $\;1+\sqrt2\;$ ,since the other root of the quadratic is negative: $\;1-\sqrt2<0\;$ .