# Finding the explicit formula for a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

There is a recursive sequence defined by: $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n/(4\cdot a_n + 3)$.
I've also been given this sequence: $b_n = (2\cdot a_n + 1)/a_n$ and I have found that $b_{n+1} = 3 \cdot b_n$.
How can I find the explicit formula of $a$?

Comment: Well, $b_n=3^n$.

Comment: wow thanks! i did not think about that now its easy, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693), I detailed the steps for solving a first-order rational difference equation such as
$${ a_{n+1} = \frac{m\,a_n + x}{a_n + y} }$$

For your case $m=\frac 14$, $x=0$, $y=\frac 34$ makes the problem quite simple. Just follow the steps.

Comment: yes thanks! the comment below my question solved my problem i just did not know how to close the question