# Nonlinear recurrence equation solution

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find a solution to the following recurrence:

$$
R_n=A+\frac{2AR_{n-1}}{2A+R_{n-1}}
$$

I don't see any simple way to find the solution to this, but WolframAlpha gives the following elegant solution (unfortunately without steps):

$$
R_n=A\left(2-\frac{3}{c_14^{n+1}+1}\right)
$$

For some constant $c_1$ I can find setting $R_0$. I tried to linearize it so far without success. Is there some other method I miss here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want a proof of the result or do you want to know how to come up with such a solution (if you get a slightly different problem in the future)? Because the proof is trivial- you just plug in the resulting expression in both sides

Comment: @AlbertParadek No, I can prove it easily by induction, but I want the reasoning on how to get from the recurrence to the solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$R_n - 2A = \frac{2AR_{n-1}}{2A + R_{n-1}} -A = \frac{AR_{n-1} - 2A^2}{2A + R_{n-1}} = \frac{A(R_{n-1}-2A)}{(R_{n-1}-2A) +4A}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{R_n - 2A} = \frac{(R_{n-1}-2A) +4A}{A(R_{n-1}-2A)} = \frac{1}{A} + 4\cdot  \frac{1}{R_{n-1} - 2A}$$

By denoting $x_n =  \frac{1}{R_n - 2A}$, we have:

$$\begin{align} 
 & x_n = 4 x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{A}\\
&\implies \left(x_n + \frac{1}{3A}  \right) = 4\left(x_{n-1} +\frac{1}{3A}   \right)\\
& \implies   \left(x_n + \frac{1}{3A}  \right) = 4\left(x_{n-1} +\frac{1}{3A}   \right) =...= 4^n \left(x_0 + \frac{1}{3A}  \right)\\
& \implies x_n = 4^n \left(x_0 + \frac{1}{3A}  \right) - \frac{1}{3A}  \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, we deduce easily $R_n$ via this expression

$$\frac{1}{R_n -4A} = 4^n \left(\frac{1}{R_0 -4A} + \frac{1}{3A}  \right) - \frac{1}{3A}$$
and $c_1$ must be equal to

$$c_1 = \frac{1}{R_0 -4A} + \frac{1}{3A}$$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solution for $c_1$ proffered by @NN2 in the equation provided by the OP. I find that they do not conform to a direct calculation of the recurrence relation.

I have two problems here. In the first place, I do not agree with the WA solution. I have found consistent error with WA where they have exponents of $n+1$ where it should be $n$. Thus, I suggest that the solution should be

$$
R_n=A\left(2-\frac{3}{c_14^n+1}\right)
$$

This is consistent with my own derivation of the closed form. In that case, we can find $c_1$ directly from this equation as follows

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{R_0}{A}-2=-\frac{3}{c_1+1}\\
&\frac{c_1+1}{3}=-\frac{A}{R_0-2A}\\
&c_1=-\frac{3A}{R_0-2A}-1=-\frac{R_0+A}{R_0-2A}\\
\end{align}
$$

This result has been tested against (a) the recurrence relation, (b) my own closed-form solution, and (c) two formulations of the Rational/Ricotti Difference Equation, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_difference_equation),  which I have programmed previously. I have tested these solutions with random complex numbers for both $R_0$ and $A$.