# Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_1 = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = \dfrac{2x_n + 1}{x_n+3}$ for $n ∈ \Bbb{N}$ converges and determine its limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_1 = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = \dfrac{2x_n + 1}{x_n+3}$ for $n ∈ \Bbb{N}$ converges and determine its limit.

I understand how to show the limit of sequence, but how could I show that it is decreasing?
I tried to do it by induction:
$$
x_{n+1} =\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
x_{n+2} = \frac{2x_{n+1} + 1}{x_{n+1} + 3} \\
x_{n+2} < x_{n+1} \\
\frac{2x_{n+1} + 1}{x_{n+1} + 3} < \frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
\text{Then I put } x_{n+1} =\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \text{ at the left part of the equation} \\
\frac{2{(\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} )} + 1}{(\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3}) + 3} < \frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
\frac{x_n^2 + 4x_n + 3}{x_n^2 + 5x_n + 6}< \frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
({2x_n +1})({x_n^2 + 5x_n + 6})< ({x_n^2 +4x_n +3})({x_n + 3}) \\
{x_n^3+4x_n^2+2x_n-3>0}
$$
And I don't know what to do next and I can't determine its limit until I proof that it's converges

Comment: Use induction. And please use Latex formatting.

Comment: I tried to use induction, but I did something wrong(

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: To show it's decreasing, find $x_{n+1}-x_n$. You should get a quadratic that is negative for all $x_n>\frac{\sqrt 5-1}2=0.618...$, which proves that $x_{n+1}<x_n$

Comment: $$
x_{n+1} =\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
x_{n+2} = \frac{2x_{n+1} + 1}{x_{n+1} + 3} \\
x_{n+2} < x_{n+1} \\
\frac{2x_{n+1} + 1}{x_{n+1} + 3} < \frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
\text{Then I put } x_{n+1} =\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \text{ at the left part of the equation} \\
\frac{2{(\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} )} + 1}{(\frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3}) + 3} < \frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
\frac{x_n^2 + 4x_n + 3}{x_n^2 + 5x_n + 6}< \frac{2x_n + 1}{x_n + 3} \\
({2x_n +1})({x_n^2 + 5x_n + 6})< ({x_n^2 +4x_n +3})({x_n + 3}) \\
{x_n^3+4x_n^2+2x_n-3>0}
$$ And I don't know what to do next(

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885418/finding-the-closed-form-of-a-recursive-sequence/3885693#3885693

Comment: Calling $\phi(x) = \frac{2x+1}{x+3}$ we have $|\phi'(x)| < 1$ for $x\ge 1$ then follows $|x_{k+1}-x_k| \ge |x_k-x_{k-1}|$

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

$$x_{n+1}=2-\frac{5}{x_n+3}$$

Since $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0.75$, so $x_2<x_1$. Suppose that for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ we have that $x_{n+1}<x_{n}$. Then:

$$x_{n+1}+3<x_{n}+3$$
$$\frac{1}{x_{n}+3}<\frac{1}{x_{n+1}+3}$$
$$2-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}+3}<2-\frac{1}{x_{n}+3}$$
$$x_{n+2}<x_{n+1}$$

So by first principle of mathematical induction the it follows that $x_{n+1}<x_{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Now all that remains to be shown is that this is bounded below then by Monotone Convergence Theorem you can easily deduce the convergence and therefore find the limit.

Comment: Thanks. It was exactly what I needed!

Comment: You can then click the tick mark on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{2 x_n+1}{x_n+3} \cdots (*)$ for any integer $n\ge 1.$ We note that $x_n$ is positive and hence bounded below by $0$.

Let the proposition be $P(n): x_{n+1}\le x_{n}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}.$
$x_2=\frac34<x_1 \Rightarrow P(1)   $ is true.

Assume that $P(k)$ is true for some natural number $k$, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{k+2} & =\frac{2 x_{k+1}+1}{x_{k+1}+3} \\
& =2-\frac{5}{x_{k+1}+3} \\
& <2-\frac{5}{x_{k+3}} \\
& =\frac{2 x_k+1}{x_k+3} \\
& =x_{k+1}
\end{aligned} $$
Therefore $P(k+1)$ is also true. By M.I., $P(n)$ is always true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ So the sequence $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below and hence is convergent, say, to $L$. Taking limit of $n$ to infinity on both sides of $(*)$ yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
& L=\frac{2 L+1}{L+3} \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & L^2+L-1=0  \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & L=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$